# Testing RecentlyViewed object records

Tags: apex, unit-test, recentlyviewed

I've got an Apex class with simple method returning recently viewed records using 'RecentlyViewed' object type. The issue is with inserting test data for unit tests because LastViewedDate field is not writeable so I can't mark my test records as recently viewed.

Do you have idea how to workaround this problem? Is there a trick to mark records as recently viewed via apex code? Or do I have to simply view several records in my Salesforce App and then hardcode their Id in my test method?

Comment: Would you not be able to query the Ids that are in the RecentlyViewed table and assert your inserted data is present within a set time period for LastViewedDate?

Comment: @TSmith That would require `SeeAllData` to be enabled and would also require that data exist in the org.

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case, the simplest way to test your class would be to use `Test.loadData` as described in Apex Docs under [Loading Test Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm). You'd need to create a CSV file containing records which had recently been viewed, then exported. The file would be saved as a static resource that would be accessed in both your sandbox and in your production orgs for your test class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I've got another issue. I've made csv file with 3 accounts and field LastViewedDate. Everytime I add this file to static resources and get it in test method, compiler says: "CSV Pasre error: '2016-12-02 12:02:02' is not a valid value for the type xds:dateTime". Code is almost the same https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm - just added LastViewedDate fields do CSV. Any solutions?

Comment: What are your file export settings for the CSV file? Are you using text/CSV or text/plain and what kind of options might you be specifying? It may be looking for AM/PM to follow those times unless you have it set for 24 hour time format. Is that in GMT or your Local Time Zone?

Comment: I don't know how to check it. I'm just using notepad.exe ANSI coding and save file to .csv.  MIME type is application/vnd.ms-excel.

Comment: I suspect that's the issue. You've set the mime type to vnd.ms-excel. Try setting it to plain text/csv. Also, if you're on Windows, you'll want to use the Windows ISO character set who's number I can't recall at the moment. Check your org to see what the default setting for your users is, that's the one you'll want to use.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question. Everytime i make csv files in my system all of them are in format vnd.ms-excel, no matter i make them in excel, notepad, notepad++... how to make csv file with mime-type 'text/CSV'?

Comment: I recommend you use DataLoader to do your export. The DateTime should be in the format of something like `2015-01-08T17:11:27.000Z` where `T` denotes Time and `17:11:27.000Z` denotes that the time is in 24 hour format based on GMT (thus the Z for Zulu), not the local time zone. That's the information that's missing from your CSV files. You could of course choose to edit them to make them look like the above.